# Strange grey lines on illustrator? how do i get rid of them?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

im very confused. Never seen these before; How do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 4):

**There are two ways to create crop marks.**

**1.** It can be done from the "object menu" These crop marks are directly editable. You can turn them off in the layers panel, or just by clicking on them and pressing delete.

[image]

[image]

**2.** Another way to add crop marks is from the "Effects" panel

[image]

I'm guessing that you accidentally did this. These can be deleted (select the 'crop marks'layer and then click the little garbage can) or turned off (clicking the little eye) from the "appearance" side panel. Select one of your shapes and then check it's effects in the the "appearance" panel. From the screenshot you added, it looks like all of your shapes have this effect added.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are most probably crop areas or artboards, depending on your Illustrator version. Try the artboard / crop area tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, as in the letter, not a zero) and yoou'll most probably be able to resize and get rid of rectangular areas.

These grey lines are the indicators for those areas.

Comment: That did not get rid of it! Thanks for the reply though.