# Remove black streaks in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, illustrator-effects

I just started learning Illustrator and I attempted to create a book logo. Everything worked out, except when I tried to create a 3D effect (extrude and bevel), some unpleasant black streaks appeared on the canvas. It happened a couple of times before, but they later disappeared. This time, however, the black streaks were perpetual, even when I export my file. I couldn't select the streaks either to delete them. The following picture contains the streaks which I circled in red.
[image: logo with black streaks]
How can I remove those? They seem to be part of the lower dark brown panel, but I can't delete it.

*Related: [Strange grey lines on illustrator? how do i get rid of them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/39337/strange-grey-lines-on-illustrator-how-do-i-get-rid-of-them/39345)*

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult assist with any sort of definitive answer here. This is *very* specific to your files.

If you *don't* have an actual object creating these black marks, then it could be an issue with AI's 3D effect which has *always* been a bit poor.

Sometimes a slight rotation of 1° or 2° in the 3D effect will correct things like this. You simply need to pay close attention when applying the 3D effect.

Comment: Hmm. that didn't seem to work. Also, the black streaks seem to be part of the lower object in the image (the dark brown panel). I have no idea how to remove it though.

Comment: @code they *appear* to possible be crop or trim marks. You have to remove them from the original artwork.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You have to find them in the artwork and delete them. They aren't added randomly. They *must* be in the art.

Comment: Well, I know where they are, but I can't select them, so I can't delete them (or I'll delete the dark brown platform as well).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, I simply deleted the crop marks. I selected the element, then Window --> Appearance --> Crop marks, delete, and it all disappeared.

Comment: @user287001 Wow, it must be very easy for you to make something like that. It took me hours. Can you describe your process? I had difficulty getting the lower stone's extrude and bevel effect to show up on the right side... Also, how can I ensure that the stones align? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the upper stone looks skewed though... can you explain? To me (an amateur designer) it looks fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused... the upper stone isn't made to be 90° from the lower one. I purposely tilted it back a little to resemble kind of like an open book. It's also meant to be a `B`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132253/discussion-between-user287001-and-code).